# Reposition UIPrintInteractionController on rotate

Tags: ios, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I am using a `UIPrintInteractionController` to display print options inside of my application.

Currently it is presents using the `presentFromRect:inView:animated:completionHandler:` method. This works great and positions the print options perfectly.

When I rotate the device, the arrow now moves to an incorrect position and the print controller view is also moved (along the x axis to be exact).

This happens with both orientations, but it significantly worse from portrait to landscape. If it helps, the popover stays positioned on the Y axis exactly as it should.

I have tried a couple options including recalling `presentFromRect:inView:animated:completionHandler:` in `didRotateToOrientation` and this method:

```
- (void)popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController willRepositionPopoverToRect:(inout CGRect *)rect inView:(inout UIView *__autoreleasing *)view
```

This has a worse effect, where the print options disappear entirely. Also, `UIPrintInteractionController` is an `NSObject` and somehow behind the scenes Apple somehow puts it into a popover controller.

Any ideas on what to do?